# Creating Dummy Data

Tags: r, if-statement, dummy-data

what is the difference between `==1` and `==-1` in these following codes?

```
mydata1=data.frame(State=ifelse(sign(rnorm(6))==-1,"Mina","Mani"),Q1=sample(1:6))
mydata2= data.frame(State=ifelse(sign(rnorm(6))==1,"Mina","Mani"),Q1=sample(1:6))
```

Comment: The code is just assigning 'Mani' and 'Mina' randomly with equal probability. There is no significant difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the -1 is just an inversion of the TRUE/FALSE operator in your code.
You can reproduce your code with `set.seed(x)`

Sign() produces you 1 and -1, so if you take your example:

```
sign(rnorm(6))
```

> [1] -1 -1  1  1  1  1

so if you take the equal operator, you just ask if it's -1 or 1. Actually you want to generate randomly the names in your code, so it doesn't make any difference. But for understanding here what happens if you switch the numbers:

```
set.seed((123))
sign(rnorm(6))==-1
```

> [1] TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

```
set.seed((123))
sign(rnorm(6))==1
```

> [1]  FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

with this information your code proceeds